# multiple auto increment in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, auto-increment

I'm using php and mysql. I have a table with the id column set to auto increment as the primary key. I'm trying to add another column called sort_order. The sort_order column should auto increment when the row is inserted. Then a user will be able to change the sort_order value. But mysql does not allow auto increment for more than one column?

What is the best way to auto increment the sort_order value?

**By popular Request, some more explanation.**

In administration area, the user will have a list of categories. Using javascript the user can drag the order they want the categories in. The script then posts a list of all the ids in the new order, and the sort_order values in the old order.

I then have a php function which updates mysql with the new sort_order value.

All of this is already done, except I had manually filled out all the sort_order values. I want it to be able to have a value when a user creates a new category.

Then I can use the sort_order to display the category order correctly on the front end.

I have everything done already. But in development I manually filled in the values for the sort_order.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about how you're going to use the `sort_order` column?

Comment: What exactly you need the second auto_increment column for? I don't understand reasoning behind this.

Comment: If you can detail about the usage, may be we can suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use a trigger, cf http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html

Comment: The link is not available anymore. Downvoting it.

Answer (score 7):

You can leave your **sort** column equal to NULL by default. The only thing you need is a little smarter query. For instance:

```
select * 
from something
order by ifnull(sort, id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to update your row upon insert, or choose an appropriate value in your PHP code at the time the query is produced.

However, you should consider whether you really need to create an auto-incrementing sort_order value. In your display code, you can sort items that have been given an explicit sort order, and place the remaining unsorted items at the appropriate place (bottom?) in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add a timestamp and sort on that, which actually adds meaning to your data model.  A "sort_order" column means you're putting presentation (view) logic into your data model, which is a Bad Thing.

Comment: Depends on the actual usage, but sometimes a sort order is actually part of the data model imo. Consider a gallery. Yes, sort order is related to presentation, but it is also part of the model because the order of presentation is both arbitrary and important to the gallery as a whole. You can't just go with the primary key or a timestamp, since those values are meant to be static. In that circumstance, a sort key makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

You may store 0 in sort_order and then sort by `sort_order + id`. Results will be same because  `sort_order` will be exact 0 instead of `id` ( less on `id`)