# How do I make another MySQL auto increment column?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

MySQL doesn't support multiple auto increment columns.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Is there another solution to make the value of column `order` increase automatically when I insert a new record?

Comment: there is also the "rowid" that goes up every inserted line :       select rowid from parts where id = somenumber

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085275/multiple-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: So, you want two fields to be both auto_incemented and both store the exact same values in all rows?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it from within your application by issuing another query that increases `order` or you can create a trigger that does that for you. Whatever you do, for the sake of sanity of programming world - don't use reserved words for column names such as `order` :)

Comment: For the sake of sanity of programming world you got to escape column names with backticks and never ever have any problems with reserved words.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want 2 fields to be auto incremented - they will have the same values anyway so you can just use ID.

If you want to have your invoices/orders to have sequential numbers then you should keep that numbering in separate table and haves separate logic to update those numbers.

Comment: They might be 'offset' from eachother, or possibly OP wants to 'close up holes' in the autoincrements. This article is MSSQL but might be relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349092/can-a-sql-server-table-have-two-identity-columns

Comment: MySQL only assigns an auto-incremented id if you don't specify one yourself. Thus you could use it to automatically assign a new value if none was filled in, but still allow the explicit choice of any of the existing values. So they wouldn't have to be the same for each record.

Comment: For example we need two IDs when implementing temporal tables. On ID will be system and second ID will be used to identify record: 'id', 'country_id'

Comment: You might want the column to be unique and auto-increment by default but at the same time you might want the be able to freely switch values e.g. the order in a list. If you were to reassign ID's this would obviously be very bad for existing relations. I don't see why you'd want another table for this logic either?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your original table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

How about this single insert query:

```
INSERT INTO `parts` (`name`, `order`) 
SELECT 'name of new part', IFNULL(MAX(`order`), 0) + 1 FROM parts;
```

If the claim is true that this is not a safe query, one can simply introduce table locking as follows:

```
LOCK TABLES `parts` AS t1 WRITE, `parts` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `parts` (`name`, `order`) 
SELECT 'name of new part', IFNULL(MAX(`order`), 0) + 1 FROM `parts` AS t1;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Have not been able to produce any issues with this query; 50 queries in parallel, and still does not cause any duplicates. Is there a source where it says that this kind of query can cause issues?

Comment: @sanmai Added table locking to my answer. Would still like to have an explanation of when this single query - without table locking - would cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to set only `order` field as AUTO_INCREMENT; and calculate new value for the `id` field manually. Here it is an example -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `order`)
) ENGINE=myisam DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

-- Add some new rows with manually auto-incremented id:

--    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1 INTO @next_id FROM parts;
--    INSERT INTO parts VALUES(@next_id, '', NULL);
--    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1 INTO @next_id FROM parts;
--    INSERT INTO parts VALUES(@next_id, '', NULL);

  INSERT INTO parts SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1, '', NULL FROM parts;
  INSERT INTO parts SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1, '', NULL FROM parts;

SELECT * FROM parts;
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | order |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 |      |     1 |
|  2 |      |     1 |
+----+------+-------+


-- Add some new rows for specified `id`, the value for `order` field will be set automatically:

INSERT INTO parts VALUES(2, '', NULL);
INSERT INTO parts VALUES(2, '', NULL);

+----+------+-------+
| id | name | order |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 |      |     1 |
|  2 |      |     1 |
|  2 |      |     2 |
|  2 |      |     3 |
+----+------+-------+
```

Comment: Yes, table can be locked. ...I edited my answer, now SELECT and INSERT statements are replaced with one INSERT...SELECT statement; in this case we can do it without locking.

Comment: INSERT...SELECT isn't safe from race conditions

Comment: Please explain why you think so.

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, if anybody need this again you can use this trigger.
It increment `order` by +1 based on `id` and it works on multiple insert values

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON parts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`order` < 0 THEN
        SET NEW.`order` = (select id from parts order by id desc limit 1) +1;
    ELSEIF NEW.`order` > 0 THEN
        SET NEW.`order` = (select id from parts order by id desc limit 1) +1;
    ELSEIF NEW.`order` is null THEN
        SET NEW.`order` = (select id from parts order by id desc limit 1) +1;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider adding a second table for the `order` column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parts_order` (
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Example usage:

```
-- First we insert a new empty row into `parts_order`
INSERT INTO `parts_order` VALUES (NULL);
-- Next we insert a new row into `parts` with last inserted id from `parts_order`
INSERT INTO `parts` SET `name` = "new name", `order` = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This approach does not require transactions nor locking.

Comment: Table is MyISAM, why transaction then?

Comment: If you read carefully, you'll see that the table type is MyISAM. That table type does NOT support transactions. Whether it's "good" or not, transactions **will not work** with MyISAM.

Comment: Okay, I removed that section.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think too far _ just add the last_id to your order String and thats it :)
I solved it this way that I added a string let's say "Order_2018_00" + LAST_INSERT_ID().
So this field is unique for each added set :)