# Inserting auto_number another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
MessageID (autonumber), ParentMessageID, Message, User
```

I would like to create a `SQL INSERT` query that will populate `ParentMessageID` with the same result as `MessageID`.

Can this be done in one query instead of using server side coding to insert the first row and then update the record with the ParentMessageID.

Comment: By `auto_number` I assume you mean `auto_increment`

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344587/making-another-mysql-auto-increment-colomn

Comment: You can also use a [Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) to update the ParentMessageID and set it equal to MessageID

Comment: From the MySQl forum: `http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,186171,186171` a Trigger was used

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL trigger to update a field to the value of id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211792/mysql-trigger-to-update-a-field-to-the-value-of-id)