# Laravel Migration return Incorrect table definition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel Migration return "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key", why?
[Link of Code](http://paste.ofcode.org/6fPqVMhqFp6dDXHgaGAaJd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, consider some [atomizing](https://ochre.uchicago.edu/page/more-data-organization).

The second argument for `integer` values when creating migrations is NOT the length of the field but rather if it should or it should not be autoincrement.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/330d11ba8cd3d6c0a54a1125943526b126147b5f/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L443

That's where your problem lies.

For example `$table->integer('celular',15)->nullable();`. Laravel will assume you want that to be autoincrement as well since `15` is a truthy value and since mysql [doesn't allow more than one column to be autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344587/how-do-i-make-another-mysql-auto-increment-column) you got yourself an error.

Answer (score 0):

check your table structure you most probably want to build a table with two auto increment columns, which is not possible

Answer (score 0):

`$table->increments('id')->primary()` instead of `$table->increments('id')` should work. As the error message did say you have not defined the column as primary key