# MariaDB - setting a next biggest value with UPDATE

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table `racuni` which has a column `id_racuna` that only has `NULL` values in it.

[image]

This is the table creation query:

```
CREATE TABLE racuni
(
    id_interesa     INT UNSIGNED    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
    id_racuna       INT UNSIGNED    NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_interesa)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

As you can see, `AUTO_INCREMENT` has already been used on the primary key so I can't use it anymore to increment `id_racuna`. So I tried to use this query:

```
UPDATE racuni
SET id_racuna = CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT id_racuna FROM racuni ORDER BY id_racuna DESC LIMIT 1) IS NULL THEN 1
                    ELSE id_racuna +1
                END
WHERE id_interesa IN (2);
```

But I get an error:

[image]

I have seen people using aliases to solve this problem but they usualy deal with `INSERT` statements, so I am kind of lost here. How could I use aliases in my case? In the book from Ben Forta I read that aliases are provided using `AS` keyword, but people on this forum don't use it...

Comment: MySQL does not support more than one auto increment column (q.v. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344587/how-do-i-make-another-mysql-auto-increment-column)).

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I know. I also pointed that out in the third paragraph.

Comment: The first problem with your logic is _which_ `NULL` value get assigned to 1?

Comment: Well this is needed only for the first non `NULL` value in the column.

Comment: This sounds like what you need:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-sequence/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
set @id := 0;
update racuni r 
    set id_racuna = (@id := @id + 1);
```

I don't know where the condition on `id_interesa` comes in.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit? This is the first time I see `:=`. And why do you say `update racuni r`?

Comment: @71GA . . . That is variable assignment.  It is rather important in MySQL/ MariaDB because these databases lack other functionality (such as CTEs and window functions).