# MySQL Two auto_increment columns

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [multiple auto increment in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085275/multiple-auto-increment-in-mysql)

I have a table called `projects` and I want to make two columns both auto_increment. I want the `id` and the `order` columns to auto_increment and both be unique.

How can I do this in MySQL?

Here is my create syntax so far:

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
   `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
   `order` int(6) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `order` (`order`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: wouldn't they both have the same value for every record?

Comment: @luchosrock The order key would be editable by the user to reorder projects in a list. Projects would then be ordered by the order column.

Comment: If it's going to be editable why make it unique?

Comment: @Sharlike The field itself won't be editable by the user. The user will get to Drag & Drop to reorder projects and my project class will work out the numbers to update the order field.