# Creating 2 columns with AUTO_INCREMENT on InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have 2 id columns: one is the table/system id, which has no meaning and should always be auto incremented. The second one is a business ID, which NOT ALWAYS will be set a value on insert, and may be set an incrementing number anytime after Insert.

So I was planning on using the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO setting, but from what I've read InnoDB doesn't support 2 auto_increment columns. Any workaround I can use here?

Comment: If a column has no meaning, why is it there?

Comment: There are plenty of topics on this. You need to use a trigger for your second column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple auto increment in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085275/multiple-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Comment: On top of other comments, auto_increment **must** always be primary key and having 2 primary keys is illogical (and not supported), therefore implied solution is a trigger - as @njk said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have 2 auto-increment in one table or 2 TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

your options:

- Is to create a trigger.
- redesign your DB, because if you need to have 2 auto_increment not null, that means that you will have 2 unique keys not null (PK) in that table, which it's not good.

How to create a trigger: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html

Comment: Ok thanks -- about databse design, my business ID can be null; its value is set when a "person" becomes a "client".  And on the trigger, how about concurrency? I will have to select the latest ID, add 1 and then update it ; in this meantime a new record can be inserted. Is locking table for updates the best option?

Comment: there is a Mysql function that return the last inserted id, take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id